# Android Gradle identify current falvor at compile time

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How is it possible to identify the current flavor being compiled. I'm trying to add a file to compile only if I'm compiling a certain product flavor.

```
buildTypes {

     android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
         variant.productFlavors.each() { flavor ->
            if (flavor.name.equals(currentFlavorName)) {
```

The problem is that I can't seem to find where the currentFlavourName of the flavor which I am currently building is located.

Comment: what kind of file do you want to add? I think there is an easier way ..

Comment: I want to be able to control which strings.xml file i use according to what type of flavor I am compiling. where type is referring to something specific which can be true or false not debug or release.

Answer (score 0):

just put the strings you want for flavor1 into:

```
src/flavor1/res/values/strings.xml
```

and the strings for flavor2 into:

```
src/flavor2/res/values/strings.xml
```

no need to put logic into your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Android uses a unique build process regarding your resources for different flavors and it is very easy to control.

if you set up your main source:

```
project-name
------------/app
---------------/src
-------------------/main
------------------------/res
----------------------------/values
------------------------/java
-------------------/development
-------------------------------/res
-----------------------------------/values
-------------------------------/java
-------------------/production
------------------------------/res
----------------------------------/values
------------------------------/java
```

This would be a bottom up approach from product flavor into main. Meaning if you have a strings.xml with items having the same name existing in development/res/values and have values that also exist in main/res/values/strings.xml these will be over written (and same would go for the production flavor) based on the build variant defined in your gradle file.

```
android {
  productFlavors {
    production {
        applicationId "com.test.prod"
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    development {
        applicationId "com.test.dev"
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if exits a method to get the currentFlavor. I haven't found it yet.

A ugly solution can be

```
variant.productFlavors.each() { flavor ->
       if (flavor.name.equals("flavor1")) {
           //..........
       }
}
```

However, if you want to be able to control which strings.xml you are using, you can achieve it in different ways.

First of all you can just define a xml file in your flavor folder.

```
app/src/main/res/values/    -> for common resources
app/src/flavor1/res/values  -> resources for flavor1
app/src/flavor2/res/values  -> resources for flavor2
```

This doesn't require any config in your `build.gradle` script.

A second option is to define a resource value using `build.gradle`.
Something like:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "IRCEnterprise"
    }
    //....
}
```

Another option is to create some field in your BuildConfig class using this kind of script.

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        buildConfigField "String", "name", "\"MY FLAVOR NAME\""
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to copy the required type of string file when i create it. I want to be able to select it and have it compiled for that flavor. There are a lot of strings so resValue would be quite unfitting. BuildConfig is similar to resValue and does neither serve my pupose.

Comment: @JY2k In this case you have to follow the option1. You have to use different strings.xml for each flavor leaving the common string in the main folder.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I asked how to identify the current flavor at compile time in the build.gradle file.

Comment: @JY2k Sorry. I was following your comment "I want to be able to control which strings.xml file" and I think that my answer can be a way to achieve it instead of identifying the current flavor. To be honest I didn't find it in last months. In any case I have updated the answer.